# Выполнение скрипта при посещении файла

Tags: javascript, python, php, веб-программирование

Возможно-ли сделать выполнение скрипта при заходе на конкретный файлы?

Ну допустим, у меня есть веб-страница [example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Leucanthemum_vulgare_%27Filigran%27_Flower_2200px.jpg/1126px-Leucanthemum_vulgare_%27Filigran%27_Flower_2200px.jpg), где при посещении этого файла, именно исполняемого (Те, в этой ситуации с расширением .jpg) - у меня должен выполняться скрипт(Желательно php).
Очень важно при этом сохранить расширение, а не использовать редиректы - то-есть чисто цельный файл flower.jpg

Comment: Вы можете "замаскировать" файл, как запрос. То есть получаете сам файл запрашиваемый в скрипте, выполняете какие-либо действия и отдаете этот файл. Примерно так

Comment: Увы это не подходит под мою цель, я написал выше что мне нужен именно скрипт на самом файле.

Comment: А почему бы не обрабатывать весь урл и выполнять скрипты по маскам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
while True:
   f = open('Файл')
   if f.closed:
      # если файл закрыт...
   else:
       # файл открыт
```

Comment: Спасибо! А могу-ли я получать какие-либо данные клиента, открывшего файл?

Comment: Да, но смотря от куда.

Comment: Ну мне нужно получить его юзер эджент, операционную систему и ip - это возможно?
Допустим когда клиент заходит на файл flower.png

Comment: да, возможно. Используйте модули

Answer (score 0):

Создаёте на сервере папку **flower.jpg** и внутри неё файл **index.php** с примерно таким содержимым:

```
<?php
 // ... тут какой-то PHP-скрипт ...
?>
<img src="flower.jpg" />
```

В ссылках на эту станицу указываем такой URL: `https://[весь путь]/flower.jpg` Скрипт выполняется, расширение сохраняется.

Но это к сожалению не назовёшь тем, что скрипт находится внутри файла. Исправить можно так - сначала на компьютере упаковать скрипт во внутрь файла таким образом: создать текстовый документ, скажем, **script.php** и в нём сам скрипт. Потом из командной строки склеить одно с другим такой командой:

```
copy/b 1.jpg + script.php 2.jpg
```

, где **1.jpg** скажем, исходный графический файл, а **2.jpg** уже упакованный. (можно не из командной строки, а с помощью bat-файла) Теперь то, что получилось, отправляем на сервак. Там нужно как-то сделать, чтобы этот файл при посещении открылся с помощью архиватора win-rar. Оба упакованных файла окажутся среди тех, что нужно разархивировать. Как автоматически разархивировать - тоже не знаю, но верю, что это всё возможно. И после разорхивации останется запустить файл **script.php** на выполнение.

Comment: Увы не-то, тем более мне нужно выполнять скрипт на сервере